# PytzUsageWarning doesn't seem to go away

Tags: python, binance, pytz

Okay so every time I work with the datetime library I get an error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/dateparser/date_parser.py:35: PytzUsageWarning: The localize method is no longer necessary, as this time zone supports the fold attribute (PEP 495). For more details on migrating to a PEP 495-compliant implementation, see https://pytz-deprecation-shim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html
  date_obj = stz.localize(date_obj)
```

This is since I downgraded from Python 3.9 to 3.7 because some libraries I used don't support Python 3.7 yet. I tried following the instructions to migrate but it really doesn't seem to work or I am just too dumb. It doesn't break my code it's just annoying.

EDIT:
Nevermind sorry about all that guys
I'm using the binance API and it seems so that that is the cause of the exception and not the datetime module itself.

Comment: What did you try? What was the error? What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: Its not an error since it doesnt crash my bot. If you go to the link in the exception it says that they updated something and how to migrate to the new version. I tried everything they are saying and i still get that exception.

Comment: Please, edit your question and give a complete, runnable example of what you tried.

Comment: what do you mean by "*work with the datetime library*"? pytz ≠ Python datetime. "*downgraded from Python 3.9 to 3.7*" - the warning says Python 3.8. "*following the instructions to migrate*" - migrate what? to where? Try to take a step back and clarify the question.

Comment: well okay to clarify my problem:
i get this error although im am NOT using pytz. Thats weird think number #1. Weird thing number #2 is that it says "The localize method is no longer necessary" although nowhere in my code I use the localize method (not in the slightest)
It here says python3.8 because thats from a friend I get the same message with 3.7

Comment: ok seems binance [depends on dateparser](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/blob/master/requirements.txt) - tried to upgrade that separately? if using pip ➠ `pip install dateparser pytz --upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

One approach to avoid that warning is, as mentioned in this post https://github.com/scrapinghub/dateparser/issues/1013#issuecomment-1109403189, to pass the timezone via the settings parameter as such:

```py
dateparser.parse(value, settings={'TIMEZONE': 'UTC'})
```

https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#timezone-related-configurations

> Can be timezone abbreviation or any of [tz database name as given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  [*ie: `CET`*]